# Why is not $e^{x}e^{-iy}$ not complex differentiable nor holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm struggling a bit with finding out why $e^{x}e^{-iy}$ is neither complex differentiable or holomorphic. Would someone mind explaining why? In the past i've learnt that the exponential function is atleast complex differentiable at some point.

I've checked if the derivitives satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations, which gets me that it satisfies one the two. But i dont really know how to find out if there is any way that

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

is equal at some point.

$u(x,y)=e^x\cos(-y)$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=e^{x}\cos(-y)$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=e^{x}\sin(-y)$

$v(x,y)=e^x\sin(-y)$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=e^{x}\sin(-y)$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-e^{x}\cos(-y)$

Thanks!

Comment: If it is differentiable at some point then so is $e^{x+iy}e^{x-iy}=e^{2x}$. But you can see that this funciton is not differentiable at any point.

Comment: If you want a function to be holomorphic the Cauchy-Riemann equations need to be satisfied at every point. So if you get a condition that is not true in general, you are already done, the function is not holomorpic. Whether there are some specific values $x,y$ where it is satisfied is not relevant.

Comment: It is important to remember that
$$\text{analytic}\begin{matrix}\implies \\ \nLeftarrow\end{matrix} \text{satisfies CR equations}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the set of differentiability (*or analyticity possibly*), just look for the set of values of $z$ which satisfy $\partial f/\partial\overline z=0.$ In your case, $\frac{\partial }{\partial\overline z}(e^{\overline z})=e^{\overline z}=0$ holds for no values of $z$, so the set is empty. 
You may like to see a similar question  [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524930/using-cauchy-riemann-equations-on-holomorphic-sets/4525075#4525075)

Answer (score 0):

Complex differentiable is the same as holomorphic.

The exponential function is holomorphic at every point, but the function $z\mapsto\overline z$ is [antiholomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiholomorphic_function).

That is why your composite function $z\mapsto e^{\overline z}$ is (at every point) antiholomorphic and not holomorphic.

Comment: I've understood it like holomorphic is a stronger criteria than complex differentiable? For example a function can be complex differentiable along a line, but since a line isnt an open set it is not holomorphic along the line. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @zzz__ notions complex differentiable and holomorphic coincide on open sets.

Comment: I agree ... "complex differentiable" can hold at a single point only, but "holomorphic"  must hold in a neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

You calculated partial derivatives in Cauchy-Riemann equations. Let's check when the equations are satisfied:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \iff e^x \cos(-y) = -e^x\cos(-y)\iff \cos(-y) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \iff e^x \sin(-y) = -e^x\sin(-y)\iff \sin(-y) = 0$$

For which $y\in\mathbb R$ is both sine and cosine of $-y$ zero?

Comment: Alright, so its just "basic" knowledge, to find points where it satisfies CR? And since it doesnt exist a -y where both equations is 0 it is done?

Comment: @zzz__ yes, function $f\colon \mathbb C \to  \mathbb C$ is $\mathbb C$-differentiable at point $z = x + iy$ if and only if is $ \mathbb R$-differentiable when regarded as function $f\colon  \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ and CR equations hold. Since there is no point where CR equations hold, your function is not complex differentiable anywhere and you are done.